# repeat the song when the command is used again

Tags: discord.py

I want it to say the same file again when using the command again but it doesn't work please help

```
@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    voicechannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name='text')
    vc = await voicechannel.connect()
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('deneme/audio.mp3'), after=lambda e: print('done', e))
```